# Try deserialize to object

Tags: c#

I have serializaed objects of different types as strings in sql table.

Now need to deserialize them without knowing what type is the object.

I am looking for sth like TryDeserializeToObject trying with different types.

Offcourse I could use try catch, is there any better way ?

Comment: You just need to store a type identifier in the serialized data

Answer (score 1):

`BinaryFormatter` stores the type info, so you could store base64-encoded strings. Or you manually store the type info at the beginning of each object's string.

Comment: I know it stores, but how to get that infor before deserializing ?